# Read from stdin, stderr in Python

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

I have two programs: p1 and p2. I run p1 | p2. I know how to read stdout from p1 in p2 stdin. How can I do the same with stderr.

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: this doesn't seem python related but bash related, since you're obviously using pipe. You could either redirect stderr to stdout or use 2| instead of |

Answer (score 3):

A pipe (`|`) in most (or all) shells takes the stdout of a command and passes it to the second command.

Taking the stderr from the first command can therefore only be done on the command line. In bash you'd do it this way:

```
p1 2>&1 | p2
```

This tells bash to forward stderr to stdout. Both are then piped to p2.

Alternatively you can make p1 print everything to stdout only.

Comment: Thanks, if I print stdin from p2, how can I know in which position was sent stderr and stdout from p1 ?

Comment: Sorry but you need to be more specific about your problem.